# How to integrate a time picker in Richfaces and bind it to a jsf managed bean

Tags: jsf, richfaces, timepicker, managed-bean

Could you please explain me how to integrate a **time picker** component into my **JSF/Richfaces** web app, and **bind its value** to a managed bean?

I know the **rich:calendar** component comes out with both a date and a time pickers, but I need the latter only. In particular I need to provide a time selector to the user, so that he/she can select a FROM time and a TO time, where they are both limited to specific min/max values read from the bean.

I can probably use js/jquery widgets with they're corresponding richfaces components, but I didn't understand how to properly use them and bind them to the bean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rich:calendar is for choosing date and its time picker is optional, I think you should write it yourself, just put two rich:inputNumberSpinner for hours and minutes.

```
<rich:inputNumberSpinner value="#{myBean.hours}" minValue="0" maxValue="23" />
<rich:inputNumberSpinner value="#{myBean.minutes}" minValue="0" maxValue="59" />
```

In MyBean class define two integer properties, hours and minutes; then add getters and setters for them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was already thinking about that kind of solution, but the fact that the "00" minute would be displayed as "0" worries me a bit. Do you think it could be a problem for the look and feel of my web app? Based on my requirements I actually need to display two time pickers (Start Time and End Time), and dynamically update their value based on the user selection. E.g.: if the user selects a Start Time greater than the End Time, the latter should be updated with the same value as the Start Time. How can I achieve this using some javascript? Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on a web application that needs a component for choosing time like you, and I could not found anything better than inputNumberSpinner for this, unfortunately richfaces 4.0 does not support number formatting for inputNumberSpinner but I think it is not a problem in look and feel of my web app. For your second question, I prefer to change minimum and maximum attributes in myBean by ajax request because I don't like to write javascript code when JSF, Richfaces and ManagedBeans exist!

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your point: min and max values should be set through ajax requests and managed beans. However, in my case I need to update their value dynamically based on the user selection. If the start time (which is a composition of two input spinners) is greater then the end time (composition of other two spinners), then the latter should be updated accordingly (e.g. make it bigger). I think ajax shouldn't be used in this case because you don't want to get back to the server each time the user clicks on the spinner; js is more appropriate for this  "presentation feature".

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake there. I meant to say I have to dynamically change the **current value** of both the start time and end time based on the user selection. Min and max values are set only once through ajax requests. Javascript is used to update the current value of the input spinners when the user clicks on them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code for start and end time pickers with client side validation, hope it helps.

**timePicker.xhtml** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>TimePicker</title>
    <script src="./resources/js/timeValidator.js"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <rich:panel>
        <h:form id="form1">
            <h:panelGrid border="1" rules="all" columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Start time" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="HH:" />
                    <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="h1" minValue="0" maxValue="23"
                        onchange="validate('form1:h1','form1:m1','form1:h2','form1:m2',true)" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="MM:" />
                    <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="m1" minValue="0" maxValue="59"
                        onchange="validate('form1:h1','form1:m1','form1:h2','form1:m2',true)">
                    </rich:inputNumberSpinner>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="End time" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="HH:" />
                    <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="h2" minValue="0" maxValue="23"
                        onchange="validate('form1:h1','form1:m1','form1:h2','form1:m2',false)" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="MM:" />
                    <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="m2" minValue="0" maxValue="59"
                        onchange="validate('form1:h1','form1:m1','form1:h2','form1:m2',false)" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and **resources/js/timeValidator.js** :

```
function validate(stHourId, stMinId, enHourId, enMinId, stChanged) {
    var stHour = RichFaces.$(stHourId).getValue();
    var stMin = RichFaces.$(stMinId).getValue();
    var enHour = RichFaces.$(enHourId).getValue();
    var enMin = RichFaces.$(enMinId).getValue();
    if (stChanged) {
        if (enHour < stHour) {
            enHour = stHour;
        } else if (enHour == stHour && enMin < stMin) {
            enMin = stMin;
        }
    } else {
        if (enHour < stHour) {
            stHour = enHour;
        } else if (enHour == stHour && enMin < stMin) {
            stMin = enMin;
        }
    }
    RichFaces.$(stHourId).setValue(stHour);
    RichFaces.$(stMinId).setValue(stMin);
    RichFaces.$(enHourId).setValue(enHour);
    RichFaces.$(enMinId).setValue(enMin);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, that's exactly what I was doing! I've also realized I have to dynamically change both the min and max values, and I think the only way I can achieve that is to get back to the server everytime a new hour is selected (the minute range depends on the selected hour -> basically the start time and the end time do not use the full range of minutes), change the min and max values for the minute spinner and refresh it. I found a way to solve it in javascript, but it didn't work when you had either the DOWN or UP button **always** pressed...Thanks again.